# Azure mobile service version conflict with Microsoft.Build.Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I just created my first Azure mobile service. After I published the service the service health changed to critical and I get following error:

"Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework': 4.0.0.0, 14.0.0.0. Please change your project to use only one version."

How can I resolve this error? In my dependencies I cannot find something like Microsoft.Build.Framework.

Comment: Can you tell us about your project.  How are you editing the project (I'm assuming Visual Studio)?  What version of Visual Studio?  What code did you write to create the mobile service?  Did you start with the quick start package?  What packages did you add to the project?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the NuGet references in your project don't match what is hosted in Azure.

The best way to ensure you don't have any issues is to download the quickstart solution from the Azure Portal and deploy that. The latest versions of the NuGet packages will makes sure that you don't introduce incompatible dependencies. See this tutorial for more: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/#test-the-app-against-the-local-mobile-service